# how to generate different js files name using ng build?

Tags: javascript, angular, deployment

I created an angular 14 app and its when I am using ng build to deploy the app to the web server. it always  generate the same js files names, which make problem by the user that they need always to clear the cache in each time there is an update to the website, ho to solve this , or how to generate always different js files names?

i changed the names manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The --output-hashing option without a parameter generates unique filenames only for files that have changed since the last "ng build" command.

**ng build --output-hashing**

The --output-hashing option with the "all" parameter generates unique filenames for all output files, whether they have been changed or not.

**ng build --output-hashing=all**

For example, if you use the --output-hashing option without a parameter, and then re-execute "ng build" without changing the files that were generated during the last execution, the files will keep their original names and no new names will be generated.